# How Do I Query In Groovier Way?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have `User` class which has a field `type`, which is in turn a list.

So `type` might look like : `["a","b"]`

I have a another list, say `search` like `["c","b"]` (this is pre-defined)

Now what I want is to search **all** my `User` instances such that I can find users `type` matching with any one of the elements from `search`.

I came up with a partial solution :

```
def newQ = User.findAllByUsernameIsNotNull()
newQ.each { eachIndex ->
                    query = eachIndex.type
                    result = query.findAll { it == "c" }
                    if(result.size() > 0 )
                    {
                        ans << eachIndex.username
                    }
                  }
```

The above code works, `ans` list have all `User` which satisfy my condition. But you can clearly see that in `query.findAll` line, I'm doing a search only for one element from `search`. I want to perform search operation for all `search` element against `query`(which is `User`'s `type` field).

How can I achieve that? Apart from my solution are there any easy way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work with a field named "type" ? "type" looks like reserved keyword : http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html

Comment: @Philippe : Actually it does but I now changed the name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def ans = []
search.each{s->
    ans += User.findAll("from User u where u.username is not null and ? in elements(u.type)",[s])
}
```

I can't think of a way to do it in a single query

Comment: I couldn't find a way either; it would be cool to be able to do something like `User.withCriteria { type { inList(search) } }` but it doesn't seem to work. BTW, you may add `and u.username is not null` to the query so it does the same as the original code :)

Comment: it seems to be elegant way to query, but using this throwing me an error :  `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException: No property found for name [all] for class [class mnm.schedule.User]`. Anything wrong?

Comment: Try it with the parameters in a list (I've updated my original code)

Comment: @Ant's what's the error? Doco for findAll is here: http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html

Answer (score 0):

```
User.withCriteria {
  isNotNull("username")
  'in' ("type", search)
}
```

Comment: I think this won't work, as the 'type' attribute is a collection, not a single value.

Comment: From @Ant's code I assume it's either a `def List<String> type` or a `static hasMany = [type: String]` in the User class (notice that `type` is used as a collection).

Comment: so, it will be better if u redesign your domain classes. create persistent enum for 'type' and use relations. after that writing query will be simplier :)

Answer (score 0):

When searching you want to go to the database as few times as possible since those are usually the most expensive operations.  If the User.withCriteria {..} works I'd use that (I'm not as familiar with .withCriteria{}).  This would work as well if you still wanted to use the dynamic finders since mockDomain doesn't work with HSQL (again not sure if .withCriteria{} works with mockDomain).

```
def search = ["c", "b"]
def users = User.findAllByUsernameIsNotNull()
users = users.findAll {it.type.intersect(search)}
```